# Import error in a inline .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, import

I have a import directive in my inline .aspx page (no code-behind).

Getting an error: The type or namespace name 'Dts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What is the issue?  Do I need a /bin directory with the .dll in it or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like there is no "project".  In that case, to reference a dll (assembly) you use an [`<%@ Assembly >`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d864zc1k.aspx) directive.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="microsoft.sqlserver.manageddts.dll" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime" %>
```

Comment: is the .dll suppose to be in lower case like that?

Comment: I doubt it matters, but it wouldn't hurt to match case.  Rather than re-type I just copy/pasted the name from Will's post.

Comment: you do realize that now programmers around the world are going to make that same 'casing' mistake :)  (thanks!)

Comment: Earn another 929 rep and you can fix it yourself. Here: have 10 to get you started. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does your project reference microsoft.sqlserver.manageddts.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Don't you love SharePoint... I had to do Code Infront for a feature that referenced Oracle:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OracleClient" %>
```

and then I can reference the classes from this OracleClient assembly:
OracleConnection, OracleCommand, OracleDataReader

Bad part was, I got no compilation errors, and had to use the wonderfully useful SmartPart (son-of or "ReturnOfSmartPartv1_3.wsp" from codeplex: http://smartpart.codeplex.com/).

I got no compile errors but it was showing nothing for my SharePoint Feature (from a code-inline ASCX)... I actually did have compile errors but it "said" it succeeded compiling in VS.NET... so I used SmartPart to do host the control with everything commented out, then I uncommented and hit F5/refresh.

I got compilation errors - with line numbers - in the SmartPart container! Funky cool!!
So now my ASCX works just fine since I can use SmartPart to see it work or not and if not, WHY!